# Android Open Source Project - How to debug java code and view XML's as graphical Representation

Tags: android, android-xml, android-source, eclipse-juno, android-debug

I need some information related to Android open source project as i have started looking into it for some reverse engineering.

1. How can we debug Android system services (other than logger option) e.g notification, network (i am using Eclipse Juno). I can debug stock apps but finding hard luck for system services.
2. Is there a way to view layout XML "Graphical Representational" in Eclipse for AOSP e.g Calendar app, Calculator App etc.

Guys i have already done Google around these but no luck. Need your opinions/insight on these please.

Help Appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is difficult to debug Android source. I usually use a lot of log.d to help debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The debugging depends on what process the service is hosted in.

If you want to debug ActivityManager, Network services, they are hosted in a Java application called system_server.

To debug these types of services, please check [Debugging Android Java framework services](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/debugging-android-java-framework.html) article.

If the service is hosted in pure native application (i.e. SurfaceFlinger), you need gdb/gdbserver type setup to debug them. Please check [Debugging native framework services](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/07/debugging-android-native-applications.html) on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Log` for debugging system services. If you understand how `Android` system works, how services work, then `Log` will be enough for debugging. Seems like there is no alternative for debugging services without running you `ROM` on real device or emulator (services are started by `Zygote` process in `Dalvik VM` sandbox).
 For better undestanding how application looks and works I'm importing application in IDE (`Intellij IDEA` for ex.), where I can easily open layouts in `Android Designer plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import sdk/sources/android-17/ as a project to your IDE
2. Run emulator
3. Start Android Debug Monitor
4. Check list of processes listed by Monitor and their ports
5. Start remote debugging session using port listed by Monitor e.g in Intellij Remote > change port from 5005 to whatever Monitor is saying e.g 8602